# How to use link_to in Rails to fill out the id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem. I am making a Rails app and it is a simple one. Customers and Invoices.

I am showing a Customer and their invoices. Iw ant to have a Details button to show the Details of an invoice.

But I dont know how to do it with link_to.

My route for the invoices is:

```
 customer_invoice GET    /customers/:customer_id/invoices/:id(.:format)      invoices#show
```

And the code for the ink at the moment is:

```
<%= link_to 'Details', customer_invoice_path(@customer) %>
```

By doing this every detail button just tries to call

```
/customers/:customer_id/invoices/:customer_id
```

So the last :customer_id should be the id of the invoice but I dont know how to do it.

This didnt work:

```
<%= link_to 'Details', customer_invoice_path(@customer, @invoice) %>
```

and jsut gives me a "compile error" (is this the right term?) in the browser.

Any ideas?

Edit: Ok Ive got it by trial and error:

```
<%= link_to 'Details', customer_invoice_path(@customer, invoice.id) %>
```

Comment: Add the content of the error (from your console, not the browser) to your question.

Comment: Ive got it....I jsut had to do invoice.id instead of @invoice

Comment: Then I suppose your error is that you have `invoice`, but not `@invoice` (presumably, you're doing this in a `@customer.invoices.each do |invoice|` loop), in which case you should be able to do `customer_invoice_path(@customer, invoice)`.

Comment: youre totally right. I just learnt something thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your error is that you have `invoice`, but not `@invoice` (presumably, you're doing this in a `@customer.invoices.each do |invoice| loop`), in which case you should be able to do `customer_invoice_path(@customer, invoice)`.